# knockoutjs use logical or with enable binding on html

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

With knockoutjs I'm trying to do something that I think is fairly simple and is supported but I can't get it to work.

I've got three checkboxes, call them A, B, and C. I've also got the select/option dropdowns that I want to enable based on these checkboxes, call them Field 1, 2, and 3.

The catch is, the enable disable mapping is like this:
Box A enabled = Field 1 enabled,
Box B enabled = Field 1 and 2 enabled,
Box C enabled = Field 3 enabled.

My HTML code is below:

```
<div id="checkboxesContainer">
    <div>
    <!-- Label elements removed for smaller code -->
        <input id="main-checkbox-1" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: box1" />
        <input id="main-checkbox-2" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: box2" />
        <input id="main-checkbox-3" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: box3" />
</div>
<div id="selectsContainer">
<!-- Label elements removed for smaller code -->
    <div>
        <select id="main-select-1" data-bind="options: workouts, optionsText: 'WorkoutName', value: selectedWorkout, enable: box1 || box2"></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select id="main-select-2" data-bind="enable: box2"></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select id="main-select-3" data-bind="enable: box3"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my knockouts js view model code for enabling the selects is below - I shortened it too because everything related to knockout.js is working:

```
self.box1 = ko.observable(false);
self.box2 = ko.observable(false);
self.box3 = ko.observable(false);
```

How come my enable: box1 || box2 doesn't enable that select when either of them are checked? I would like to avoid subscribing to changes from the checkbox observables and flipping the booleans myself if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever there are more then one condition, use parenthesis(eg. box1() || box2()).
make binding like this:-

```
   <select id="main-select-1" data-bind="options: workouts, optionsText: 'WorkoutName', value: selectedWorkout, enable: box1() || box2()"></select>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5zmSK/)

Answer (score 1):

+1 for akhlesh, but I would go one step further and move the calculation inside a computed on the viewModel to clean up the HTML and keep that information inside the view model

[**Fiddler Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4J9sB/1/)

```
<select id="main-select-1" data-bind="options: workouts, optionsText: 'WorkoutName', value: selectedWorkout, enable: enableSelect1"></select>



var vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.box1 = ko.observable(false);
    self.box2 = ko.observable(false);
    self.box3 = ko.observable(false);
    self.selectedWorkout = ko.observable();
    self.workouts = ko.observableArray([{
        WorkoutName: 'Workout 1'
    }, {
        WorkoutName: 'Workout 2'
    }, {
        WorkoutName: 'Workout 3'
    }, {
        WorkoutName: 'Workout 4'
    }, ]);

    self.enableSelect1 = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self.box1() || self.box2();
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    });
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `box1 || box2` inside of parentheses, like this: `enable: (box1 || box2)`.